# ¿Se puede mandar información a otra pantalla aparte del monitor desde la misma computadora?

Tags: java

Es decir en la computadora usen el programa de venta de boletos pero desde la misma computadora mandar otro formulario con información a otra pantalla no se si me doy a entender?

Comment: Lee [ask]: tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones, por lo tanto, lo más probable es que termine cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

si ya vi como aquí la solución: si a alguien le sirve solo es dar click derecho en escritorio y configuración de pantalla y si la pc tiene dos salidas de tarjeta de video por ejemplo en mi motherboard yo tengo por VGA el monitor y a la pantalla conectada por el hdmi y así te detecta windows en automático y ya solo le damos en extender pantalla y en java al entrar al sistema dejo otro form aparte y lo arrastro a la otra pantalla y ahí lo maximizo y ya puedo programar videos informativos en ese form que muestra en la segunda pantalla. Saludos